# AngularJS - Limit ng-init within element

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to limit the variables created using ng-init within the element and not accessible to other element?

Kindly check the example below.

**Expected result:**
Clicking the button beside the value of `myVal` should only change the value of `myVal` within the same `<div>`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <div ng-init="myVal = 1">
    {{myVal}}
    <button ng-click="myVal = myVal+1">Adds 1</button>
  </div>
  
  <div ng-init="myVal = 1">
    {{myVal}}
    <button ng-click="myVal = myVal+1">Adds 1</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. It is possible but it depends on what you want to do. The first question is, why would you have two identical div blocks? Were you actually trying to do it in a ng-repeat? If so, you can use $index to distinguish the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do by using **`two separate controllers`** which will hold the scope in two divs,

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl1", function($scope) {
 
});
app.controller("myCtrl2", function($scope) {
 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
   <div  ng-controller="myCtrl1" ng-init="myVal = 1">
    {{myVal}}
    <button ng-click="myVal = myVal+1">Adds 1</button>
  </div>
  
  <div  ng-controller="myCtrl2" ng-init="myVal = 1">
    {{myVal}}
    <button ng-click="myVal = myVal+1">Adds 1</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This answer did the trick! Thanks @Sajeetharan. Just to add, I only created a single controller and declared to both which still did the trick. It seems that Angular creates another instance of the controller.

Comment: @MichaelArdan you are welcome. yes but remember that values will be replaced